# Question about requiring Facebook App ID and secret

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, app-id

I hope someone can answer my question here, it would be really appreciated.

I'm working on a project where Facebook users should be able to login with their Facebookaccount (username or e-mail and password) and then be able to pick their businesspage in order to see their statistics (things as likes, maybe other statistics if possible).

My question is, does every single user that would like to use this service have to get an Facebook App ID, Secret etc. or does only the service needs his own App ID/Secret etc?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Robin

Comment: Of course not every user needs their own app id and secret, that would basically mean each of them would be _creating_ their own app. If _you_ want to provide an app for other people to use, then only _you_ need to create an app.

Comment: Thanks misorude. I hoped and thought that. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: btw, never ask users for username or password. you need to implement a proper app login.

Comment: Thanks @luschn I understand :)

Answer (score 0):

even after letting user logged in, you need app id to use Facebook Graph api for page insights, and for that, you need to manually create app id in Facebook developer section

Comment: Hi Trinkal, so your saying that every user should create his or her own Facebook APP ID?

Comment: I understand Trinkal but it's not like every user should get this API and create a APP ID is it?

Comment: yes, it is , every extension for facebook comes with documentation on how to create app in facebook developer account and get that app id to use

either it facebook login, or bot etc